# função equals de objeto não é chamada durante o teste unitário

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Estou desenvolvendo teste unitário de uma classe com *Junit* e *Mockito*, e pra facilitar a criação de um `spy` dessa classe eu criei uma função que constrói e retorna esse `spy`. O problema que está ocorrendo é que no fluxo da chamada que é efetuada para realizar o teste, quando é feita a chamada do método `equals` desse spy, em vez de chamar a função implementada na classe, está chamando uma função da classe `MethodInterceptorFilter`. Alguém sabe como fazer ele pegar a função implementada na classe?

função de teste:

```
@Test
public void requisicaoInvalidaNomeDuplicado() {
    prov.add(umProvTO("Premio", 5, new BenTO( 32, new BigDecimal(200) )));
    prov.add(umProvTO("Premio", 10, new BenTO( 32, new BigDecimal(500) )));

    assertEquals(false, requisicao.validarNomeDuplicado());
}
```

implementação da função `validarNomeDuplicado()`

```
private List<ProvTO> provs;

public boolean validarNomeDuplicado() {
    for (ProvTO prov : provs) {
        if (Collections.frequency(provs, prov) > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

classe `ProvTO`:

```
private String nome;

[...]

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!(obj instanceof ProvTO)) {
        return false;
    }
    ProvTO other = (ProvTO) obj;
    if (nome == null) {
        if (other.nome != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!nome.equals(other.nome)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Você pode validar se o trecho de código publicado está correto? A função validarNomeDuplicado está acessando provs e não prov. E existe uma classe umProvTO.java?

Comment: `provs` é de `private List<ProvTO> provs;`

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente existe um problema no design do seu teste.
Qual a razão de criar um `spy` dessa classe `ProvTO`? Você cria o `spy`, mas em nenhum momento vejo você utilizando o `verify`.

O `spy` é utilizado para verificar as interações da classe. Ele é utilizado para um tipo específico de teste. Por exemplo, imagine que nesse método `validarNomeDuplicado` você chamasse algum outro método:

```
public boolean validarNomeDuplicado() {
    procedimento();
    for (ProvTO prov : provs) {
        if (Collections.frequency(provs, prov) > 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Ao testar o método `validarNomeDuplicado`, você quer saber se o método `procedimento` foi chamado. Nesse caso, cria-se um `spy` do objeto que possui o método `validarNomeDuplicado`:

```
requisicao = Mockito.spy(new ProvTO());
```

E o teste ficaria dessa forma:

```
@Test
public void requisicaoInvalidaNomeDuplicado() {
    prov.add(umProvTO("Premio"));
    prov.add(umProvTO("Premio"));

    assertEquals(true, requisicao.validarNomeDuplicado());
    verify(requisicao).procedimento();
}
```

Se o método `procedimento` não for chamado será lançado um erro de

> Wanted but not invoked

No seu caso, o `spy` que você criou não parece fazer sentido. Em relação ao método `equals`. De fato, o equals do `ProvTO` não será chamado, pois ao chamar o método `Mockito.spy`, será criado um `wrapper` do objeto `ProvTO`. Quando você realiza essa chamada:

```
prov.add(umProvTO("Premio"))
```

você está passando um outro objeto que possui outro método `equals`. Se você quer testar o método `equals` real, você tem que utilizar o objeto real.